# IGListKit - How to add cell when there is a value in view model and not add one when there is not?

Tags: swift, iglistkit

How to add cell when there is a value in view model and not add one, when there is not? 
What i mean is that I'm using ListBindingSectionController and for every cell type(image, caption, etc) I have separate ViewModel class. Posts will have pictures, but may not have caption. My question is: How can I add caption cell when there is a caption whit the post, and not add one when there isn't caption?

My Caption ViewModel class:

```
import Foundation
import IGListKit

final class CaptionViewModel: ListDiffable {

  let fullName: String
  let caption: String? // can be nil(empty). When it is empty, I don't want caption cell inserted.


  init(fullName: String, caption: String?) {
    self.fullName = fullName
    if caption != nil {
      self.caption = caption
    } else {
      self.caption = " "
    }
  }

  //MARK: ListDiffable
  func diffIdentifier() -> NSObjectProtocol {
    return "caption" as NSObjectProtocol
  }

  func isEqual(toDiffableObject object: ListDiffable?) -> Bool {
    // not completed
    return false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This determination should happen in the `objectsForListAdapter` function. In `objectsForListAdapter`, it should look something like this:

```swift
func objectsForListAdapter(listAdapter: ListAdapter) -> [ListDiffable] {
  var objects = []
  // ...snip...
  if captionViewModel.caption != nil {
      object.append(captionViewModel)
  }
  // ...snip...
  return objects
}
```